# Searching name from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the name in mysql database table like `Mohan Krishna`. How we can search for that name using php with searching like `mohankrishna` name?

Comment: You can use LIKE or RLIKE , both will work for you

Comment: explain some more !!  single column contains `Mohan Krishna` ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(name,' ','')) LIKE LOWER('%mohankrishna%')
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. It makes your head spin when you start looking at all the possibilities, doesn't it. BTW I think LIKE is case-insensitive anyway, so LOWER isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but could be a good approach.

One way would be, using the full text functionality of MySQL.

Another way by using `LIKE` in your `SELECT`-query just like.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "mohankrishna";`

But I'm not really familiar with this and I don't know how tolerant MySQL is to give you the exact record.

Comment: It won't find `Mohan Krishna`

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where  where replace(name," ","") like '%mohankrishna%'
```

Comment: It won't find `Mohan Krishna`

Comment: @manurajhada:sorry I didnt get the question, now the answer is updated

Answer (score 1):

eg: `SELECT column_1 from prefix_my_table WHERE column_2 LIKE '%Mohan%';`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question

Comment: he wants to do search for `mohankrishna` not for `mohan`!!